# Query a table by value in main form and load subform - Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

When I open Order Form, it should show the list of products already present in that order in a 'ProductsCartForm'

My tables are as below:

**OrderTable:**

OrderId - Autonumber
CustName
ShipAddress
Amount

**ProductCartTable**

ID - unique
OrderId - one orderId may hold many productIds
ProductId
Quantity
UnitCost

I want to create 'ProductCartForm' in my main form 'OrderForm'. I have a parametrised query 'qryProductsByOrderId'. If I create a subform based on  qryProductsByOrderId, how can I pass the parameter 'orderId' to the subForm before/on Loading.

Some one pls help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use a parametrised query? If you make ProductCartTable the recordsource of your subform and link the two by OrderID you should have all you need. No VBA necessary. [http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/synchronize/linkedsubforms.asp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Roland says, no VBA necessary. This is what Access does well :)

Make your form for your Orders (necessary to have record source of `OrderTable`). Then make your form for your Products (doesn't need to be perfect, just needs to exist and have a record source of `ProductCartTable`). Save both. Close the Products form.

Go into your Orders form and drag your Products form on it. This will create the products form as a subform. It will likely populate the Master/Child links for you but if it does not you just need to write in OrderID for both because it is what joins the two record sets together.

[image]

This effectively does a left join for you. Only product records which are relevant to the order being shown will show on the subform.